# Convert Java 8 code with lambda expressions to Java 6

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-6

Can someone please help and explain to me how to convert the following Java 1.8 code to Java 1.6?

```
private java.util.Optional<Edge<T>> findEdge(Node<T> node) 
{
    return edges.stream()
                .filter(edge -> edge.isBetween(this, node))
                .findFirst();
}

public boolean removeEdge(Node<T> node)
{
    *java.util.Optional<Edge<T>> optional = findEdge(node);*
    if (optional.isPresent())
    {
        return edges.remove(optional.get());
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean hasEdge(Node<T> node)
{
    return findEdge(node).*isPresent();*
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `edges` is of type `Collection<Edge>` :

```
private Edge<T> findEdge(Node<T> node) 
{
    for (Edge edge : edges) {
        if (edge.isBetween(this, node)) {
            return edge;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You have to iterate over the `edges` until you find an edge that matches the filter criteria `edge.isBetween(this, node)` and return that edge. If you don't find any, you return null, since you don't have `Optional` is Java 6.

The other methods are even simpler - since you don't have an `Optional` wrapping your `Edge`, you simply check if the value returned from `findEdge` is null or not.

```
public boolean removeEdge(Node<T> node)
{
    Edge<T> e = findEdge(node);
    if (e != null)
    {
        return edges.remove(e);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean hasEdge(Node<T> node)
{
    return findEdge(node) != null;
}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to run some codes which I compiled in Java 1.8 but the system does not accept anything above 1.6. Thank you for explaining in detail.

Comment: so can you even help me on the above two methods and explain those too. I am a newbie in Java

Comment: So anytime I have Optional or Lambda Expressions, I try to convert them to a more simplistic form instead of conditions and blocking?

Comment: @user3337714 An Optional you'll always replace with the type wrapped by that Optional. Lambda expressions used with Streams have to be replaced with some iteration over the relevant Collections.

Answer (score 2):

**[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** can leverage your Lambda alike code logic (functional programming idioms):

```
com.google.common.base.Optional<Edge> opt = FluentIterable.<Edge>from(edges)
    .filter(new Predicate<Edge>() {
        @Override public boolean apply(Edge edge) {
            return edge.isBetween(XXX.this, node);
        }})
    .first();

if(opt.isPresent()) {...}
```

`com.google.common.base.Optional` is also generic class. And nonymous class is awkward and verbose to use, but it doesn't change your code logic. It's a trade-off, you could choose this *Guava* solution or loop one.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers mentioned here will work - i.e. using Guava and/or manually converting the Java 8 lambdas code to work with Java 6.

Another option is to use the [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) library that backports Java 8's lambda expressions and method references to Java 7, 6 and 5. Please check the project's Github page for latest details on which features are backported (since the library is under active development).